# Ant <exec> to jarsigner in jenkins - cannot execute binary file

Tags: android, jenkins, build-automation, android-auto

Im trying to use ant script to execute the jarsigner and and to sign.

The script which is running in windows machine is failing in Mac. I can see that there is some script issue .

Please check on this.

```
<target name="sign1" depends = "antrelease">
<echo>Signing 1....</echo>
<exec dir="." executable="/bin/sh">

<arg line="jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -   keystore abc.keystore -    121212  ${basedir}/workspace/temp/MobileUIOctRel/build/luaandroid/dist/DBSMobileWallet/bin/DBSMobileWallet-release-unsigned.apk dbs" />
        </exec>
</target>
```

Im getting the following error

sign1:
     [echo] Signing 1....
     [exec] /usr/bin/jarsigner: /usr/bin/jarsigner: cannot execute binary file
     [exec] Result: 126

Comment: The file is executable ? (have permission? )

Comment: Ya ..Im able to execute other lines in the ant  script .. But only this line fails.

Comment: I mean the jarsigner has permission ? not the script file

Comment: Yes. I have other android project   gradle scripts which is signing successfully